# Calligraphy font not getting applied In release build of Android app with dexguard

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dexguard, calligraphy

I have used this popular calligraphy library 
[Calligraphy](http://[1]:%20https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

**I have integrated Dex-guard in my project**

it works fine with the **proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')**

**whenever i create release build with the proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')**

i got this error in log-cat at the time of creating release build

```
: Can't create asset from fonts/Gotham/Gotham-Bold.otf. Make sure you have passed in the correct path and file name.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Gotham/Gotham-Bold.otf
    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:310)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.TypefaceUtils.load(:35)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyUtils.applyFontToTextView(:114)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyUtils.applyFontToTextView(:143)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyFactory.onViewCreatedInternal(:142)
    at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyFactory.onViewCreated(:110)
```

**altough i have also added following rules as all we know dexguard obsfucate files**

> -keep class uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy. { ; }
>   -keep class uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.*$ { ; }
>   -keep class uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.* { ; }

but in my case it didn't worked

Any help is appreciated although i tried removing and adding fonts 
i have also tried with the .ttf format as well .otf format

Answer (score 0):

Try obfuscation of assets in dexguard rules.